# Set PageIndex of DataPager

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, paging, datapager

I have a ListView that I am paging with a DataPager.  I would like to set the initial page of the pager on Page_Load.  I have tried the DataPager.SetPageProperties method but it's not doing what I need.  Here's how I'm calling this method:

```
dataPager.SetPageProperties(3, dataPager.TotalRowCount, false);
```

The line above trims the datasource to start at the third item and paging still starts at 1.  This is not what I want.  I want to keep the entire list of items and just jump to a specific page in the list.

Is there another Property and/or method of a DataPager and/or ListView that I should use?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The methods described on this page seem to work: http://leedumond.com/blog/resetting-the-page-index-in-a-listview/

Answer (score 5):

Try this. Not tested.

--edited--

```
dataPager.SetPageProperties( 
    (3 * dataPager.PageSize, 
    dataPager.MaximumRows, 
    false
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  I assumed you meant dataPager by "this.Pager" because the line you provided generated a runtime error.  So I replaced "this.Pager" with dataPager but I got a blank page with no ListView items or paging elements.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Yes, I have edited it. What are the values of datapager.PageSize and dataPager.MaximumRows?

Comment: I had a differnt challenge, but your hint helped me a lot. You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

If you're binding your datasource by code,you can manually set PageIndex in binding method.

```
grd.DataSource = something ..
grd.PageIndex = initialIndex;//where initialIndex is the index you wish to set
//you can arrange this index in your code,it's up to you actually.
grd.DataBind();
```

The point is before databinding you have to set new page index.

Best Regards 
Myra