# Applying filter on paginated page shows empty result

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a problem with paginated pages to apply filter. I have used ListView Control to display data from database & having some filters. Now problem is suppose If I view all products (18 Products per page) & having 187 Products So If I switch to 7th page & then apply price range filter then it find products from that range but showing empty result. This is my live site Link http://foxboxretail.in/products

My Datapager Code

```
protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    (products.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    products.PageIndex = 0;
    buildWhereClause();
}
```

Filter Applying Code

```
public string buildWhereClause()
{
    string pageName = string.Empty;    
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio2").ConnectionString;
    string query = "select * from products";
    string joiner = "";

    string condition = string.Empty;
    string whereClause = string.Empty;
    string priceCondition = string.Empty;

    try {
        for (i = 0; i <= priceFilter.Items.Count - 1; i++) {
            if (priceFilter.Items(i).Selected) {
                string price = priceFilter.Items(i).ToString;
                priceCondition = string.Concat(priceCondition, joiner, string.Format("'{0}'", price));
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(joiner))
                    joiner = ",";
            }
        }

        joiner = " where ";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(priceCondition)) {
            whereClause = string.Concat(whereClause, joiner, string.Format("price_range IN ({0})", priceCondition));
            joiner = " and ";
        }


        string masterClause = string.Empty;
        if (whereClause == string.Empty) {
            masterClause = (query + " Where type = @type and status = @status");
        } else {
            masterClause = (query + whereClause + " and type = @type and status = @status");
        }

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr)) {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(masterClause)) {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "product");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "active");
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        products.DataSource = dt;
                        products.DataBind();
                        itemCount.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex);
        return string.Concat(query, whereClause);
    }
}
```

UPDATE (Snapshot of datapager)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The results count says the records are found (I applied a "Rs.501 - Rs.1000" filter and there were 33 results - at least that is what the label shown) but the list is trying to show the 7th page (and there are only 2)

Try to reset the page index after filtering data.

Comment: Please let me know how to reset page?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698954/set-pageindex-of-datapager

Comment: This is not working for me. Is that anything I need to  change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `PageIndex` property of the gridview to the first page or the last page whenever you are changing the filters. Remember to bind the gridview after changing the pageindex

To set the page index to first page:

> `mygridView.PageIndex = 0;`

As you are using the DataPager for paging, you need to set as follows after the buildWhereClause :

```
(products.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, true);
```

Set the last input as **true** in the SetPagerProperties

Comment: Can you tell me how to reset pageIndex?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: PageIndex = 0 not coming in intellisense.

Comment: I have updated my code in my post in Datapager Code Section. Please review it

Comment: Move the line of PageIndex after the function call `buildWhereClause`

Comment: Please view my update on post. I have posted snap of my problem. Can you please view & let me know?

Comment: @SUN, Please check now and let me know

Comment: No. This also didn't worked. It keeps on loading page when witching to 1 to 2 page here is the link of live site which consist this problem http://foxboxretail.in/products

Comment: you also not getting where's the problem?